# setState in React not giving desired output

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Below is my code. Its giving me result as 0, 1,2 , 4, 8, 16.... Whats wrong with this. I'm new react.
    import {react,Component} from 'react'

```
class Timer extends Component{

   constructor(props){

      super(props);
      this.state={
      count:0
      }
}

updateTime(){
    setInterval(() => {
                      var number=this.state.count+1;
                     this.setState({ count:number })} , 5000);
            }

render(){
   this.updateTime()
       return(
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
        </div>
        )
    }

}
export default Timer;
```

However changing the updateTime function as below, is giving expected result

```
updateTime(){
   var number=this.state.count;
   setInterval(() => {
   number++;
   this.setState({ count:number })}, 5000);
 }
```

expected result:- increment number by 1 every 5 sec

Comment: expected result:- increment number by 1 every 5 sec.

Comment: You should include your comment of the expected result as part of the question.

Comment: I updated the updateTime function and it working fine     updateTime(){
        var number=this.state.count;
        setInterval(() => {
          number++;
             this.setState({ count:number })}, 5000);
           }
Still trying to find out whats wrong with the above one

Comment: your question is incomplete without the comment `expected result:- increment number by 1 every 5 sec` being included in the post. You should edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you render, you call `updateTime()`, which kicks off a new timer.

Only call `updateTime()` in `componentDidMount` instead of in `render`.

Make sure to clear the timer when you unmount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = this.updateTime();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
}

updateTime(){
    return setInterval(() => {
        var number=this.state.count+1;
        this.setState({ count:number })
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Got the point . But when I updated the updateTime(everything else remains the same) like below .. its working fine
    updateTime(){
        var number=this.state.count+1;
        setInterval(() => {
        number++;
        this.setState({ count:number })}, 5000);
            }

Comment: @Rahul it's still making the multiple updates, your `var number` is just always the same when the function is invoked. So state gets updated to the same thing 4 times in a row.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, click the empty checkmark next to it to help others find it in the future, and to give me fake internet points :)

Comment: @AndyRay My reputation is less than 15, my response ll be recorded but ll not change the publicly displayed score :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time the state updates, the `render()` function runs. You're calling `this.updateTime()` every time `render()` runs, which is setting the interval multiple times. After 4 render calls, you've got 4 timers runnning, each incrementing the `state.count` by 1 every time. To reduce the number of intervals, just set the interval once:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateTime();
}
```